# creating and using swap files

Tags: partitioning, mount, swap

I know very little about Linux, so probably this is easy.
I've created 2 swap files because I deleted my swap partition. When I manually mount them via terminal by:

```
swapon /var/tmp/swapfile1 

swapon /var/tmp/swapfile2
```

and inspect via:

```
more /proc/swaps
```

It all seems to work. But now I understand I must edit my boot script to mount these two files every time at startup.
Tried editing rc-sysinit.conf by adding the above lines. This doesn't seem to work. My limited knowledge of Linux prevents me from debugging this situation myself. So my question: Where should I insert the above instructions and with what syntax? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update `/etc/fstab`. Add a line for each swapfile like:

/var/tmp/swapfile1 swap swap defaults 0 0
/var/tmp/swapfile2 swap swap defaults 0 0

You probably removed the line for your old swap partition the same place, else it would be a good time to do it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works great. Is there any particular reason this didn't work in the boot script like I tried before? I seems odd to me that I can mount both files 'by hand' when logged in, but not via the startup script... Thanks again.

Comment: @RutgerMoody maybe the boot script didn't run at the right time ... but anyway the /etc/fstab is the right way to do it.